# Why my Jena modified ontology isn't working properly on protege 2000?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, protege

I initially created an ontology using Protege 2000. Than with Apache Jena java framework, i modified its content. however, when i open this modified version in Protege 2000, all my individual properties asserstions can't be found even if by checking the file's content in a text editor, these assertions exist.

> PS:
>   - All the work is XML/RDF.
>   - Even if the file is just saved (without being modified) i have the same result.

does anyone have any clue about this issue? is there a solution ?

Comment: The problem is that you can't open a Protege file in Protege after you have modified the file with java? You should have kept a backup.

Comment: yeah i still have a backup, but the problem is that, protege can open the file, All classes and individuals and their annotations are detected, however the properties of individuals aren't. :(

Comment: can you provide a minimal example or maybe the files?

Comment: @JörnHees Ok just give me some time to prepare them :)